# Passing a specific Xarry Data Variable into a New Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have a xarray dataset, with data variables of:
Data variables:
    hid      (particle) float32 ...
    d        (particle) float32 ...
    x        (particle) float32 ...
    y        (particle) float32 ...
    z        (particle) float32 ...
    image    (hologram_number, xsize, ysize) uint8 ...

I am wondering if there is a way to take all of the x values for my 10,000 data points, and pass them into a new one dimensional numpy array? Any sort of direction would be amazing. I have been reading the xarray.Dataset API and I'm not really getting anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ds.x.values`, where `ds` is the name of your dataset. `.x` (which is equivalent to `ds["x"]`) gets the x dataarray from your dataset and `.values` returns the numpy array with its values.